# i don't know how to login with google and facebook in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I wanted make a login using facebook and google accounts, this is my code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword,
     onAuthStateChanged, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth.js";
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
// login with google
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = document.querySelector('#google-icon');
signInWithGoogle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
    
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        const email = error.email;
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
          });

});
```

but i keep getting this error message:

> Info: The current domain is not authorized for OAuth operations. This will prevent signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup and linkWithRedirect from working. Add your domain (127.0.0.1) to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

can you help me, please?

Comment: Did you go to the Firebase console (the path to the panel is in the errors message) and check if `1270.0.0.1` is listed as an OAuth redirect domain?

Comment: thank you so much, i added 1270.0.0.1 to firebase console and it worked